# Unable to open tcp connection. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. exit status 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, go, sql-server-2008, port

I tried to fetch data from a SQL Server database. When I run, it keeps giving me this error:

> unable to open tcp connection with host 'localhost:1433': dial tcp [::1]:1433: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> exit status 1

---

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

var kiosk string

var server = ".\\MSSQLSERVER01"
var port = 1433
var user = "DESKTOP-37624KK"
var password = "**********"
var database = "Kiosk"

func main() {
    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d;database=%s", server, user, password, port, database)

    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in connect DB")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM Kiosk")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&kiosk); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(kiosk)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
}
```

- Checked if firewall is blocking needed port
- Tried to change and connect to new ports
- Tried to search on the internet for other solutions. Nothing has helped yet

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for over **3 years**; you should really be finalising and implementing that upgrade plan, if you aren't already.

Comment: Are you sure, that those backslashes and a dot are necessary in server name? You have mentioned firewall, so i suppose this isn't a local instance.

Comment: There are three thigs that can lead to this kind of errror (that I can think off).
1. Wrong host name 
   Unnamed instance on localhost => localhost
   Unnamed instance on other server => otherServerName
   Named instance on localhost => localhost\\instanceName
   Named instance on other server => otherServerName\\instanceName
2. TCP protocol disabled on the server
3. Firewall on the server on client machine - SQL server uses several different ports

Comment: Is this the third time you've asked this question today? [deleted #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364629/unable-to-get-instances-from-sql-server-browser-on-host-localhost-read-udp-1) [deleted #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74372747/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-exit)

Comment: They are little different. But, yes. I really has stucked on that problem and found no solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server variable value is wrong. The dot (.) means "localhost". If the SQL server is installed locally just use "." (or ".\InstanceName" - if there are multiple instances installed). If the server is installed in the network just use SERVERNAME (without the leading backslashes), or SERVERNAME\InstanceName.